# builtin array initialization without constexpr size

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, declaration, constexpr

I'm having trouble figuring out how can it be possible that I can declare a built in array without using a `constexpr` dimension. That is, the following block perfectly works for me. I knew that built in arrays have fixed size that must be specified at compile time via `constexpr` definition of the size.

```
int size;
int arr[size];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily via `constexpr`, that is something that was introduced from C++11.

You can assign the size through a simple number

```
int arr[12];
```

or a constant

```
int const size = 7;
int arr[size];
```

or a C-style macro

```
#DEFINE  size  5

int arr[size];
```

but you're right: the following code

```
int size = 11;
int arr[size];
```

isn't correct C++.

But is legal in some version of C (only in C99, if I remember well) and C++ compilers are usually C compilers too. So are usually permissive.

You can try compiling with specific options to impose a strict check about the language; by example, with g++ and clang++, I use `-ansi -pedantic`

Comment: very thanks, i'll use -pedantic from now on, while -ansi for some reason doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Also it is possible to initialize array of size `n` this way:

```
int n = 123;
int* a;
a = new int[n];
```